# Does AWS Sagemaker Batch Transform work on Images

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, yolo, yolov8

Does AWS Sagemaker Batch Transform work on images (.jpg) file types? From what I see it only supports json and CSV.

If it doesn't support, what would you recommend for inferencing? All my images are in s3 folders with a unique "transaction_id". I want to provide the transaction_id, get the images and run a yolov8 model that returns prediction results in JSON. There should only be a couple of calls a day, there is no need for a real-time endpoint.

My model is already trained so it would also be a custom image.

Comment: Hello @Jeremy Lin, have you considered passing a json file to the batch transform job with the image s3 key paths and download them within the runtime?

Comment: Hi @Jeremy Lin, while you can make it work with Batch Transform by using a custom Inference Script( input_fn()) to load the images and process them in your model_fn(). I would recommend you to switch to Async Inference, it is purpose built for such usecases, I have a blog that showcases how to do this, linking it here for reference, it comes along with a Github example - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/run-computer-vision-inference-on-large-videos-with-amazon-sagemaker-asynchronous-endpoints/